# Can't save changes in Realm DB file

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I work in iOS app and I use Realm for local DB. I've installed Realm via cocoapods and added my model classes. Everything is fine but when I opened the `default.realm` file from the simulator Documents directory in Realm browser app, I was unable to edit records or do any changes. I'm able only to add records but I can't edit fields, once I put the value in fields and navigate between classes, all changes I made disappear.

**Update:**
I see in cocoapods, the RealmSwift installed is version `(0.98.3)` and the Realm browser which is the latest from App Store is version `Version 0.97.0 (62)`. Would that be the problem?

Comment: You can download the browser as a [prerelease from the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases).

Comment: I tried it version `0.98.2 (55)` but unfortunately it doesn't work. Same issue

Comment: Try deleting the app from the simulator and installing it again if you dont have important data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double-click on a field, that should make the cell editable and you can change it's values. It might be necessary to hit 'Return' after you've made those changes for the value change to stick.

There's a new version of the Browser on its GitHub page now: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.98.3

If you're still having issues with that version and the instructions I provided above, please let me know here!

Comment: Yes it needs to hit the Return key after editing the cell.